# Column and CellLabel

Tags: cells

Is it possible to add a CellLabel over multiple lines? When trying the code

```
SetOptions[ NotebookSelect[mb], CellLabel-> Column@{"line 1", "line 2"} ]
```

with a Cell selected in the mb Notebook, nothing shows up. What's the solution for this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Not specially. One label is enough, but it should consist of several lines. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok. Now, then, is it possible to add multiple labels to one cell? Thanks for all help!

Comment: I'd like a cell to have a name with a number, for example "Cell 1.", "Cell 2." etc. But also, each cell should have a maximal mark sign, for example " \ 4" or "\ 10", different with each cell. These two lines of text should appear with each cell. Do you think that's possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba: sorry for this: I totally forgot to cast votes. My bad :)!

Comment: @Kuba: Hm, yes, I'll try to classify my cells differently then! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any formatting in cell dingbats. Try

```
Cell["A cell with a dingbat", "Text",
 CellDingbat->StyleBox["Emulated\nLabel","CellLabel"]]
```

See if you can tell it from a real one.

Comment: Good to know, thanks ;)